# Haskell print horizontal line

Tags: haskell, printing, functional-programming, line

I'm writing a function 'printLine' that - given a list of ints - returns a string containing a horizontal line. The length of this line should be the max value of the list of ints. For example:

```
printLine [1, 3, 4, 0]
```

should return:

```
+----+----+----+----+
```

(Note that the length is decided by the amount of hyphens, not the '+'-signs. There should always be 5 '+'-signs.)

I've written the following code:

```
printLine :: [Int] -> String
printLine widthList = concat $ concat $ foldr (:) [["+"]] boundList
where boundList = replicate 4 ( "+" : hyphenList )
      hyphenList = replicate max "-"
      max = maximum widthList
```

The code is working correctly, however, I feel like I've over-complicated this function. For example, I've used 'concat' twice in a function. Is there a 'cleaner' way to go about this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Part of the complication might occur because the function is trying to do too much at once. It's very unlikely that you will be reusing exactly this function any time soon. What's more, the number 4 and possibly even the characters '+' and '-' are "magic numbers".

Therefore a first step could be to turn the function into a more reusable one

```haskell
-- | renamed from "printLine" because "print" has a connotation of I/O in Haskell
separator :: Int -> String 
separator = repeatedLine 4

repeatedLine :: Int -> Int -> String
repeatedLine reps segmentWidth = ...
```

Even if you never reuse the function, the number 4 now has a name (`reps`) that identifies its purpose.

On to the core function. Your fold is both a `reverse` and a `["+"]:`. the reversal is necessary because `boundList` appends the `'+'` at the beginning. That's a nice optimization, but it makes the combination more complex. However you do it, it seems you have all these details to handle. But there's an alternative perspective: start at infinity. So you already have

```
  where segment = '+':replicate segmentWidth '-'
```

Now you want to repeat that. The simplest way to do that is with `cycle segment`, which produces an infinite list of segments. Now all you have to do is take the right prefix - which moves all the complexity into a few bits of math.

```
repeatedLine :: Int -> Int -> String
repeatedLine reps segmentWidth = take (1+reps*(segmentWidth+1)) $ cycle segment
  where segment = '+':replicate segmentWidth '-'
```

Bonus: you now have a minimal number of iterations.

Answer (score 1):

@David Fletcher's comment leads to a nice solution:

```
printLine :: [Int] -> String
printLine xs = intercalate (replicate (maximum xs) '-') (replicate 5 "+")
```

Answer (score 0):

Some remarks:

- In `hyphenList = replicate max "-"`: `"-"` is a string so `hyphenList` will be a list of strings. It would be simpler if you used `'-'` instead. This would make `hyphenList` a string and this would help you get rid one of the `concat`s.
- I would rename the variable `max` because there is already a function called `max` defined in the `Prelude`.
- You can use the [intercalate](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-List.html#v:intercalate) function from `Data.List` to simplify the fold and the other concat.
- `intercalate` will not add separators at the beginning and at the end of the generated string, so they have to be added manually.

So putting it all together you get:

```
printLine :: [Int] -> String
printLine widthList = "+" ++ intercalate "+" boundList ++ "+"
  where boundList = replicate 4 hyphenList
        hyphenList = replicate m '-'
        m = maximum widthList
```

Comment: You're missing the plus signs at the start and end - you'd get them if you did the intercalating the other way round, like `intercalate (replicate 4 '-') (replicate 5 "+")`

Comment: @DavidFletcher That's a good idea. I fixed the issue differently to stay as close to the OP as possible.